# Iterating through a list by index in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, foreach

How do I get the an integer out of the following code so that I can compare it with other integers?

```
unseenWords = ["Cat", "Geography", "Mouse", "Apocalypse", "Hierarchy", "Opaque", "Holocaust"]

for i in unseenWords:
     print(unseenWords)
```

I tried using len as following as a replacement:

```
unseenWords.__len__()
```

But that's when I get the erorr in this title. I'm very used to Java code so I'm expecting i to always be an integer but it doesn't seem to be the case in Python as it returns the actual word when i try purely try printing out the 'i'?

So when i print unseenWords i get it formatted like this:

```
['Cat', 'Geography', 'Mouse', 'Apocalypse', 'Hierarchy', 'Opaque', 'Holocaust']
['Cat', 'Geography', 'Mouse', 'Apocalypse', 'Hierarchy', 'Opaque', 'Holocaust']
['Cat', 'Geography', 'Mouse', 'Apocalypse', 'Hierarchy', 'Opaque', 'Holocaust']
['Cat', 'Geography', 'Mouse', 'Apocalypse', 'Hierarchy', 'Opaque', 'Holocaust']
['Cat', 'Geography', 'Mouse', 'Apocalypse', 'Hierarchy', 'Opaque', 'Holocaust']
['Cat', 'Geography', 'Mouse', 'Apocalypse', 'Hierarchy', 'Opaque', 'Holocaust']
['Cat', 'Geography', 'Mouse', 'Apocalypse', 'Hierarchy', 'Opaque', 'Holocaust']
```

whilst printing out the index i get it formatted like this instead:

```
print(i)

Cat
Geography
Mouse
Apocalypse
Hierarchy
Opaque
Holocaust
```

though i'm expecting it to be more like:
1
2
3
4
5
6

But how do I get the current index Number?

Comment: what output are you actually trying to get? Just a list of all indexes in the list? The relevant iterable for that is `range(0, len(unseenWords))`

Comment: `for index, i in enumerate(unseenWords):`

Comment: `for ... in ...` is just like `for(... : ...)` in java

Comment: Why do you expect to get the index? It's kind of equivalent to Java's `for (String i: unseenWords) {`. You wouldn't expect `i` to contain the index, right?

Comment: @bro-grammer line code execution 
  http://www.pythontutor.com/live.html#code=unseenWords%20%3D%20%5B%22Cat%22,%20%22Geography%22,%20%22Mouse%22,%20%22Apocalypse%22,%20%22Hierarchy%22,%20%22Opaque%22,%20%22Holocaust%22%5D%0A%0Afor%20index,%20i%20in%20enumerate%28unseenWords%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20print%28index%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=7&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-live.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false

Comment: I think you want `for i, word in enumerate(unseenWords)` and then `print(i)`.  `i` will hold the index to the word in the list, while `word` will be the corresponding element in the list.  FWIW, `for` in Python is more like a "for each" rather than a C-style for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for index, data in enumerate(unseenWords):
    print("index: "+str(index)+ " data:"+data )
```

I think it solves your problem.

Comment: Use string formatting instead of string concatenation: `print("index: {} - data: {}".format(index, data))`

Comment: yes, its a other way. Thanks

Comment: Or, better, f-strings.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm very used to Java code so I'm expecting i to always be an integer but it doesn't seem to be the case in Python as it returns the actual word when i try purely try printing out the 'i'?

Well, python is not java indeed, so why would you expect it to work the same way ? [The behaviour of python's `for` loop is documented](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements), and you're supposed to read the doc, aren't you ?

> I tried using len as following as a replacement: `unseenWords.__len__()`

Slightly OT : You're not supposed to call "magicmethods" directly (they only are the support for operators - and operators-like functions - overloading). The proper way is `len(unseenWords)`.

> But that's when I get the erorr in this title

You didn't bother posting the relevant code (which you should have), but obviously you did something like:

```
for i in `unseenWords.__len__()`:
    # ....
```

which of course raises this error - what would be the sense of iterating over an integer ? Here again, [doing at least the official tutorial would have solved your problem](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#the-range-function) (notice that it's the very next part after the explanation of the `for` loop...).

> though i'm expecting it to be more like: 1 2 3 4 5 6

Like the vast majority of languages - including Java FWIW -, python uses zero-based indexes - but `range()` can take a 'start' argument too so it's not really an issue.

Comment: I have read the document. I just don't understand it well enough hence why I go here. I don't understand why everyone on platforms like Stackoverflow expects all beginners to fully understand every concept only because they themselves understand it. It's a very selfish attitude.

Comment: @Aspect and where in your question do you mention that you've read the doc and what part of it you don't understand ? You may want to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. This being said, if you've read the doc and experimentally verified by yourself that the behaviour you get is the documented one, then I don't really get where your problem is...

Answer (score 0):

You are performing a `for-each` loop instead of iterating by index.

```
for i in unseenWords:    # for every item in the list unseenWord
    print(unseenWords)   # you print the actual list
```

This is the same as `for (String i : unseenWords)` in Java (as stated by @ChatterOne in the comments).

If you wanted to print each word you would need to do the following:

```
for i in unseenWords:
    print(i)
```

If what you want is to print the index of each word then there are some different ways to do it, one of which is the following:

```
for i in range(len(unseenWords)): # iterate on the range of the size
    print(i)
```

Comment: But `print(unseenWords)` doesn't "print said item".

Comment: My bad, fixing it

Answer (score 0):

some modification in your code, will give you your desire output. please compare below code with yours

```
unseenWords = ["Cat", "Geography", "Mouse", "Apocalypse", "Hierarchy", "Opaque", "Holocaust"]


for i in range(0,len(unseenWords),1):
   print(i)
```

**will give you :**

> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6

**just like in java we do**

```
for (int i=0; i<arrayLength; i++)
 System.out.println(i);
```

as because the indexing begins with **zero**